# Spring Security LDAP Authentication with custom login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap

I don't know how to do some stuff with spring security and I hope you guys can you help me. 
I have two controllers: one for login page and one for home page

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/rest/hello")
 public class LoginController {

   @GetMapping(value="/login")
   public String getLoginPage(Model model){
     return "login";
   }
 }
```

and

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/hello")
public class HomeController {
   @GetMapping("/home")
   public String getHomePage() {
     return "homePage";
   }
}
```

For this controllers I have html pages,

login.html

```
     <body>
         <div class="limiter">
         <div class="container-login100">
         <div class="wrap-login100">
            <div class="login100-form-title" style="background-image: url(images/bg-01.png);">

            </div>

            <form class="login100-form validate-form">
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-26" data-validate="Username is required">
                    <span class="label-input100">Username</span>
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-18" data-validate = "Password is required">
                    <span class="label-input100">Password</span>
                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter password">
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="flex-sb-m w-full p-b-30">
                    <div class="contact100-form-checkbox">
                        <input class="input-checkbox100" id="ckb1" type="checkbox" name="remember-me">
                        <label class="label-checkbox100" for="ckb1">
                            Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button class="login100-form-btn">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ldif file and a configuration that looks like that:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
}


@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource(contextSource())
            .passwordCompare()
            .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
            .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
}

@Bean
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
    return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap://localhost:8389/"), 
"dc=springframework,dc=org");
}
}
```

First of all, I want to use my login form not the default form. If I try to do this in my configuration

```
 .formLogin().loginPage("/login");
```

I receive this error: This page isn’t working
localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies

And my second problem is that after authentication I want to redirect me to the home page but instead I receive the a message with the name of the html file: "homePage"

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following.

Change the login REST controller `@Get Mapping` .

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/rest/hello")
 public class LoginController {

   @GetMapping(value="/dologin") // <---- new
   public String getLoginPage(Model model){
     return "login";
   }
 }
```

Match the above `"/dologin"` to the change in the Http configure method.

```
.formLogin().loginPage("/dologin");
```